# Git - Constructing a new branch from various selected commits on master

Tags: git

I need to release only certain stories that have passed QA. I don't have access to the branches, only the master branch.

There will be another release in two weeks, so I was thinking of just creating a 'dead-end' release branch and that I need to start this branch from the commit just prior to the last release and then merge, rebase or cherry pick commits from the master to put into my 'release branch'.

So I've checked out from that point 2 weeks ago and made a branch from it. Now I need to fold-in all the stuff I'm interested in. Actually, no I haven't. I don't think I have. On master, I checked out the old commit and then made a new branch but looking at the illegible history in gitk is it? (I'm on Windows) I think it made a branch from the head of master.

Any advice gratefully received. Please speak slowly, as I find Git more difficult than any other topic I've ever had to comprehend in my life, including derivatives pricing, Newtonian Mechanics, vector math, string theory and my wife, and judging by the votes Git questions get, so does everyone else.

Hoping this is pretty standard, considering that most teams will have stories that don't meet QA some some that do.

Comment: Not helpful for your current situation, but: You should enforce that code does not go on master, if it is not QA'ed and ready for production. This way you won't have this problem, or at least minimized it a great deal.

Comment: Yep, that's totally right, we will create a production branch when TeamCity deployment is all setup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `master` branch currently looks like this:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F <--master
```

and, assuming you want to create a new branch that consists of only `C` and `E`, along with everything up until (and including) `A`, here's the basic plan for what you would need to do:

```
git checkout -b newbranch A
git cherry-pick C E
```

This should result in this situation:

```
 A---B---C---D---E---F <--master
  \
   C'---E' <--newbranch
```

Depending on exact dependencies between `A..F` in the original `master`, you *might* get some conflicts you have to work through (e.g. if `B` introduced something, and `C` modified that something, then cherry-picking `C` will not find the stuff it wants to modify).

Comment: Thank you. Very clear and inline with what I have been reading. Unfortunately, I've immediately hit conflicts (I'd have thought the incoming changes 'won') with code that's not 'mine' so I can see that actually, I'll just hold off releasing. Instead, I'll get that production branch sorted out.

Answer (score 3):

An other option (than cherry-picking) is to perform an interactive rebase.

Still assuming your `master` branch currently looks like this:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F <--master
```

and you want a new branch with `C` and `E` :

```
git checkout -b newBranch F
git rebase -i A
```

Your favorite editor will then prompt and display all the commits between `newBranch` and `A` (A not included):

```
pick B    Message for commit B
pick C    Message for commit C
pick D    Message for commit D
pick E    Message for commit E
pick F    Message for commit F
```

Delete the line corresponding to the commits you do not want to keep, that is : B, D, F. Save and exit, and let the rebase command doing its job. And voilà !

```
A---B---C---D---E---F <--master
  \
   C'---E' <--newbranch
```

As noticed by twalberg, you may encounter conflicts during the process. In such a case the rebase command will pause for each problem, and invite you to resolve it. Once this done, just type `git rebase --continue` to proceed.

Comment: Thanks also, I'll let the votes play out as to which answer wins since I'm not qualified to say. My BA just Skyped to tell me the story I'm trying to exclude is good to go. Great timing.

Comment: @LukePuplett Under the hood, the two methods are pretty much doing the same thing - it's just two different UI-space methods for accomplishing the same thing, born out of different ways of thinking about what it is you want to accomplish. `cherry-pick` approaches it from the "build a new branch including some commits" angle, while `rebase` takes the "take an existing branch and manipulate it into the form I want" approach...